# Then prove that $\exists U$ subspace of $V$ such that $W_i \oplus U=V$ $\forall i=1,...,n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be finite dimensional vector space over an infinite field. Let $W_1, W_2,...,W_k$ are subspaces of $V$ of same dimension. Then prove that $\exists U$ subspace of $V$ such that $W_i \oplus U=V$ $\forall i=1,...,k$.

At first I was thinking in this way that suppose we start with an example that let $k=3$ and basis of $W_i$ is $\mathfrak B_i$ and $\mathfrak B_1=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$, $\mathfrak B_2=\{b_2,b_3,b_4\}$ and $\mathfrak B_3=\{b_3,b_4,b_5\}$. Then we take $  \mathfrak B_1 \cup \mathfrak B_2 \cup \mathfrak B_3$ and choose linearly independent subset say $\mathfrak B$ from that. If $Sp\{\mathfrak B\}\neq V$. Then we take the additional linearly independent vectors in the generating set of $U$ after extending $\mathfrak B$ to a basis of $V$. The main problem is how do we utilize $\mathfrak B$ in $U$. So for simplicity take $Sp\{\mathfrak B\}= V$.

Now I had an idea that suppose $ \mathfrak B= \mathfrak B_1 \cup \mathfrak B_2 \cup \mathfrak B_3$  is the basis of $V$. Then we partition $  \mathfrak B$ in this way that $\mathfrak B_1'=\mathfrak B \cap \mathfrak B_1, \mathfrak B_2'=(\mathfrak B \cap \mathfrak B_2)-\mathfrak B_1, \mathfrak B_3'=(\mathfrak B \cap \mathfrak B_3)-(\mathfrak B_1 \cup \mathfrak B_2)$. So what we get $\mathfrak B_1'=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\} $, $\mathfrak B_2'=\{b_4\}$, $\mathfrak B_3'=\{b_5\}$. Now we take one element from one set $\mathfrak B_i$ and substract from all other element of different $\mathfrak B_j$'s, this will the generating set $S$ of $U$. i.e here $S=\{b_1-b_4,b_2-b_4,b_3-b_4,b_1-b_5,b_2-b_5,b_3-b_5,b_2-b_5,b_3-b_5,b_4-b_5\}$ The elements may be repeated but we are taking $U=Sp\{S\}$. So here it works but the problem will arise if $\mathfrak B_3=\{b_1,b_2,b_4\}$ & $\mathfrak B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$(say). Then the set $S$ will be $S=\{b_1-b_4,b_2-b_4,b_3-b_4\}$. Here $W_3 \oplus U\neq V$. So how to solve this problem? If anyone have any idea please share.

Comment: Do you know about determinants? If so, you can hack together a proof using a Zariski-density argument: Setting $n = \dim V$ and $m = \dim V_i$ (the same for all $i$, by assumption), and fixing bases $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_k$ of $W_1, W_2, \ldots, W_k$, you are looking for $n-m$ vectors in $V$ which would be linearly independent if combined with the elements of each of $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_k$. Each of these linear independence relations is equivalent to a certain polynomial not vanishing. If you have $k$ polynomials over an infinite field such that each of them has a point where ...

Comment: ... it does not vanish, then there exists a point at which none of the $k$ polynomials vanishes. (This latter step is the Zariski-density argument, but it has a perfectly elementary proof.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\codim}{codim}$
You can use the *avoidance lemma*  for subspaces:

> Let $W, W_1, \dots, W_n$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$  over a field $K$. Suppose $\lvert K\rvert\ge n$. If $W\subset W_1\cup\dots\cup W_n$, then there exists $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$  such that $W\subset W_i$.

We'll proceed by induction on the common *codimension* of the subspaces $W_i$. We can suppose this codimension is $\ge 1$.

By the avoidance lemma, there exists a vector $u\in V\smallsetminus(W_1\cup\dots\cup W_n)$.

- If $\codim W_i=1$, then $W_1\oplus Ku=\dots= W_n\oplus Ku=V$
- If $\codim W_i>1$, set $W'_i=W_i\oplus Ku$. Then $\;1\le\codim W'_i=\codim W_i-1$. By the induction hypothesis, there exists a subspace $U$ such that, for all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$,
  $$V=W'_i\oplus U=W_i\oplus (Ku\oplus U).$$